# Logout button required - Can I auto logout?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Im building an application form and using the facebook login to pre-populate the users name and email address. According to the developer tools (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#login) I need to add a logout button:

*"Provide a "Log Out" option that functions properly and is easy to find."*

I don't really want to have to add a logout button to the form because it wont make sense and also adds an additional step to the form process.

So to get around this I was wondering If I can call the FB.logout() function when the user submits the form, automatically logging the user out after we've pre-populated with the data we need.

Im struggling to find support online and the Facebook docs don't cover this, has anyone done something like this before? Would this be inline with the FB policy?

Thanks

Comment: I don’t think this specific point of the policy is one they enforce with great vigor ... in that regard you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, we have a large ad account associated with the same facebook page and dont want to affect that with something like this, appreciate your feedback - I think if we dont get a definitive answer we'll give it a go and hope for the best :)